# Passwordless and keyless SSH guest access

Tags: ssh

I am trying to set up a guest user that allows `ssh` access without a password AND without a keyfile.

All my searches turns up people trying to set up password-less entry with a keyfile. This is not what I'm looking for.

I would settle for just having a blank password, but I can't get that working either; if I delete the user's password, the SSH daemon won't allow any access. I've set "`PermitEmptyPasswords yes`" in the config file and restarted the service.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're looking for is *anonymous* SSH access. I found [an article for SFTP](https://singpolyma.net/2009/11/anonymous-sftp-on-ubuntu/), which applies to SSH too, if you leave out SFTP-specific stuff:

1. Create a new user:

   ```
   adduser --disabled-password anonymous
   ```
2. Make the password actually empty:

   ```sh
   sed -i -re 's/^anonymous:[^:]+:/anonymous::/' /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
   ```
3. Allow blank passwords for SSH sessions in PAM: edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and replace the line that reads `@include common-auth` with:

   ```
   auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok
   auth requisite pam_deny.so
   auth required pam_permit.so
   ```
4. Allow blank passwords for SSH sessions of `anonymous` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

   ```
   Match user anonymous
       PermitEmptyPasswords yes
   ```
5. Restart sshd:

   ```
   systemctl reload ssh.service
   ```

I didn't try it myself, but it looks plausible, since my first thought for the culprit was PAM.

Comment: Anonymous was the missing keyword! Your solution worked perfectly, thank you so much.